# iframe source showing instead of content itself

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

When the page is rendered, the `html` source that I've set using `javascript` shows on the page instead of the content itself.

How can I show the `iframe` itself instead?

I've recieved a list of these `iframes` from a `REST api` and would like to populate them into the div.

html ..

```
<div id="1">

</div>
```

javascript ..

```
document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = '&lt;iframe class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FTTmeaE6.mp4&amp;src_secure=1&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FTTmeaE6.gifv&amp;image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FTTmeaE6h.jpg&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=video%2Fmp4&amp;schema=imgur\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/gj3ah3jw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the below code instead of yours

You had an issue on using < & > .. they don't need to be converted into & l t ; ...

```
document.getElementById('1').innerHTML = '<frame class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FTTmeaE6.mp4&amp;src_secure=1&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FTTmeaE6.gifv&amp;image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FTTmeaE6h.jpg&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=video%2Fmp4&amp;schema=imgur\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen><iframe>';
```